# Get spotify currently playing track

Tags: python, linux, spotify

**EDIT : Let's try to clarify all this.**

I'm writing a python script, and I want it to tell me the song that Spotify is currently playing.

I've tried looking for libraries that could help me but didn't find any that are still maintained and working.
I've also looked through Spotify's web API, but it does not provide any way to get that information.

The only potential solution I found would be to grab the title of my Spotify (desktop app) window. But I didn't manage to do that so far.

So basically, what I'm asking is whether anyone knows :

- How to apply the method I'm already trying to use (get the window's title from a program), either in pure python or using an intermediary shell script.

  OR
- Any other way to extract that information from Spotify's desktop app or web client.

---

**Original post :**

I'm fiddling with the idea of a python status bar for a linux environment, nothing fancy, just a script tailored to my own usage. What I'm trying to do right now is to display the currently playing track from spotify (namely, the artist and title).

There does not seem to be anything like that in their official web API. I haven't found any third party library that would do that either. Most libraries I found are either deprecated since spotify released their current API, or they are based on said API which does not do what I want.

I've also read a bunch of similar question in here, most of which had no answers, or a deprecated solution.

I thought about grabbing the window title, since it does diplay the information I need. But not only does that seem really convoluted, I also have difficulties making this happen. I was trying to get it by running a combination of the linux commands xdotools and xprop inside my script.

It's worth mentionning that since I'm already using the psutil lib for other informations, I already have access to spotify's PID.

Any idea how I could do that ?

And in case my method was the only one you can think of, any idea how to actually make it work ?

Your help will be appreciated.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking. See the How to Ask page for help clarifying this question.

Comment: @IanAuld Hopefully, this is better. Thanks.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Another nice resource to check is https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1797848 once you `set_dbus_adress` you're able to get the playing metadata with `qdbus org.mpris.MediaPlayer2.spotify /org/mpris/MediaPlayer2 org.freedesktop.DBus.Properties.Get org.mpris.MediaPlayer2.Player Metadata`

Answer (score 24, accepted):

The Spotify client on Linux implements a D-Bus interface called MPRIS - Media Player Remote Interfacing Specification.

http://specifications.freedesktop.org/mpris-spec/latest/index.html

You could access the title (and other metadata) from python like this:

```py
import dbus
session_bus = dbus.SessionBus()
spotify_bus = session_bus.get_object("org.mpris.MediaPlayer2.spotify",
                                     "/org/mpris/MediaPlayer2")
spotify_properties = dbus.Interface(spotify_bus,
                                    "org.freedesktop.DBus.Properties")
metadata = spotify_properties.Get("org.mpris.MediaPlayer2.Player", "Metadata")

# The property Metadata behaves like a python dict
for key, value in metadata.items():
    print(key, value)

# To just print the title
print(metadata['xesam:title'])
```

Comment: The Windows client does not have an api like this. OS X has an Applescript API. https://developer.spotify.com/applescript-api/ Eventually, you will be able to query the Web API for the current playing track. https://github.com/spotify/web-api/issues/12

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for ! Thanks !

Answer (score 3):

For windows:

The library can be found at github: https://github.com/XanderMJ/spotilib. Keep in mind that this is still work in progress.

Just copy the file and place it in your Python/Lib directory.

```
import spotilib
spotilib.artist() #returns the artist of the current playing song
spotilib.song() #returns the song title of the current playing song
```

spotilib.artist() returns only the first artist. I started working on an other library *spotimeta.py* to solve this issue. However, this is not working at 100% yet.

```
import spotimeta
spotimeta.artists() #returns a list of all the collaborating artists of the track
```

If an error occurs, *spotimeta.artists()* will return only the first artist (found with *spotilib.artist()*)